# Java Bean not found in configuration with multiple module

Tags: java, spring

I having a configuration problem that cause the error below. I know there are a tons of similar problem but I read a lot of answer that stackoverflow suggest with my title but I don't find the right answer yet.

```
Description:

Field collaborateurJpaRepository in com...infrastructure.persistence.user.UserRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'com...infrastructure.persistence.jurisdiction.CollaborateurJpaRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com...infrastructure.persistence.jurisdiction.CollaborateurJpaRepository' in your configuration.
```

Before to give some details of the code, I think it could be nice that I describe you brievly the context.
I work on a client project which has **8 maven modules (DDD methods)** because at the end of the year 4 modules will be separate in an other server.
Recently we create a second oracle database so I had to create multiple configuration to refer to the good dataSource. 
I think the problem is due to bad datasource configuration that block the bean spring instanciation.

We are using **spring boot version 1.5.7.release**.

**First Infrastructure configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com...jade")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "jadeEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "jadeTransactionManager")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com...jade", "org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten" })
@Profile({"ARA_JADE_CONF", "LOCAL_JADE_CONF"})
public class InfrastructureConfig {

    private final static int JDBC_FETCH_SIZE = 1000;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean jadeEntityManager() throws SQLException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSourceJade());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com...jade"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public OracleDataSource dataSourceJade() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("db.datasource.jade.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.datasource.jade.password"));
        dataSource.setURL(environment.getProperty("db.datasource.jade.url"));
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean(name="jdbcTemplateJade")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateJade() throws SQLException {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceJade());
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(JDBC_FETCH_SIZE);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException{
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(jadeEntityManager().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    } ...
```

**Seconde Infrastructure configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages =  "com.bnpparibas.sit.risk.art")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "artEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "artTransactionManager")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com...art", "org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten" })
@Profile({"LOCAL_ART_CONF,'ARA_ART_CONF"})
public class ArtInfrastructureConfig {

    private final static int JDBC_FETCH_SIZE = 1000;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean artEntityManager() throws SQLException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSourceArt());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com...art.infrastructure.persistence"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public OracleDataSource dataSourceArt() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("db.datasource.art.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.datasource.art.password"));
        dataSource.setURL(environment.getProperty("db.datasource.art.url"));
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager artTransactionManager()throws SQLException{
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(artEntityManager().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }...
```

Interface link to Entity.

```
@DDD.Repository
@Repository
public interface CollaborateurJpaRepository extends CrudRepository<Collaborateur,String>{

    @Query("FROM ART_PARAM.ART_USER u WHERE u.refogUID = :uid")
    Collaborateur findCollaborateurById(@Param("uid") String uid);
}
```

Class that contain the autowired interface to retrieve some data of the second database.

```
@DDD.RepositoryImpl
@Repository
@Primary
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private CollaborateurJpaRepository collaborateurJpaRepository;

    @Override
    //@Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheConfig.CACHE_JURIDICTION, key = CacheConfig.CACHE_KEY_UTILISATEUR_ID)
    @Transactional("entityManagerFactoryArt")
    public User retrieveUser(UserId userId) {
        if(userId.getValue() == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Collaborateur collaborateur = collaborateurJpaRepository.findOne(userId.getValue());

            return new User(collaborateur.getRefogUID(),collaborateur.getRefogFirstName(),collaborateur.getRefogLastName(),collaborateur.getProfile(),collaborateur.isActiveUser(),collaborateur.isBankingSecrecy());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the package for `CollaborateurJpaRepository`?

Comment: The package for CollaborateurJpaRepository is com.clientName.group.department.art.infrastructure.persistence.jurisdiction. 
com.clientName.group.department.art is the same for 4 modules and the 4 other modules are like that com.clientName.group.department.jade...

Comment: I found a solution to my problem by merging the both configuration class into one an only because when I start the application i didn't notice that I didn't go into the method artEntityManager contain in ArtInfrastructureConfig.class. I have to look forward my configuration to find a better solution. If someone had an idea, let's a comment! thanks